# What does this ":" operator mean, besides heritage? - usage with string to char conversion

Tags: c++, string, char, operators

I got this rather simple code here, which puts out a string, but before it's converted to single char characters.

And here's my problem, what does this ":" operator in the for loop mean / what is it exactly doing.

I only found information on heritage with this operator and the usage for simplified if branches.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void stringdemo()
{
    string s1;
    s1.assign("Hello World!");

    for (char c : s1)
    {
        cout << c;
    }
}

int main()
{
    stringdemo();
    return 0;
}
```

If someone of you knows how this operator is working, it would be glad, if you could answer me my question :) (a link to a any site, which explains this is also ok :D)

Comment: It's a range-based `for`.

Comment: You could take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: BTW, the colon, or `':'`, character, can be used to specify the width of bitfields in a struct or class.